# Radius of the largest enclosed ball in the convex hull of an algebraic variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, convex-geometry

Let $\mathcal{V}\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a real compact algebraic variety. Let $\mathcal{V}^c$ be the convex hull of $\mathcal{V}$ and let us assume that $\mathcal{V}^c$  has nonzero n-dimensional Lesbegue measure.

Question: Are there any known lower bounds  for the inner radius (=radius of largest enclosed ball)  of $\mathcal{V}^c$ (for instance in terms of the polynomials that generate $\mathcal{V})$.

Informal remark: I am especially interested in cases when $\mathcal{V}$ is generated by only a few polynomials of "low degree".

Comment: "Inner radius" = radius of largest enclosed ball?

Comment: yes, I have edited the question

Comment: you can edit the subject too...

Comment: What about the polynomial $x_1^2 + \dots + x_n^2 - \epsilon$? It seems like a pretty "good" polynomial from most perspectives, but your radius is just $\epsilon$. How do you hope to exclude this sort of thing?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Notice however that I expicitely mentioned "..in terms of polynomials that generate $\mathcal{V}$". In the problems I am studying (they have origin in quantum information) I have different varieties that can be specified by different polynomials. The point is to be able to get the lower bounds for the inner radius of $\mathcal{V}^c$ in terms of these polynomials

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer to your request for lower bounds; just some remarks.

Sometimes the center of the largest enclosed ball is called the 
[*Chebyshev center*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_center), and you can find literature under that name.
(But beware: the Chebyshev center sometimes means instead
the center of the smallest enclosing ball.)
Sometimes it is called the *ball center*.

Your $\mathcal{V}^c$ is a convex set. Finding the largest enclosed ball 
in a convex set is a convex optimization problem.
If you can approximate $\mathcal{V}^c$ with a convex polytope, then
finding the biggest ball is a linear programming problem.
E.g., these notes formulate that LP problem:
[PDF download notes](http://www.ifor.math.ethz.ch/teaching/lectures/intro_ss11/Exercises/solutionEx11-12.pdf).

A better source is

> Stephen Boyd, Lieven Vandenberghe. *Convex optimization*. Cambridge. 2004.
>   ([PDF download book](http://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf).)

They discuss the LP problem on p.148, and discuss
the problem for a general convex set p.417ff.
There they say,

> Problem (8.16) is a convex optimization problem, since each function $g_i$
>   is the
>   pointwise maximum of a family of convex functions of $x$ and $R$, hence convex.
>   However, evaluating $g_i$
>   involves solving a convex maximization problem (either
>   numerically or analytically), which may be very hard. In practice, we can find the
>   Chebyshev center only in cases where the functions $g_i$ are easy to evaluate.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will try to google for "Chebyshev center". As for the Polytope approximation: obviously in principle you can do that but I can't find much licteature about "nice" approximations of Varieties via discrete nets.

Comment: Moreover, for me it would seam to be more natural to first approximate $\mathcal{V}^c$ via spectrahedron (or its projection) and the use semidefinite programing.